# How to use R CMD INSTALL to install only essential files

Tags: r, package

I am using R CMD INSTALL to install libraries from a folder with .zip binaries to my rlibs directory. When I do this, many folders for each library are installed in the rlibs directory. Take for example the bit package. I have downloaded the bit_1.1-12.zip file from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit/index.html.

Now I install it by using the following command:

```
R CMD INSTALL --library=./r_libs ./external/bit_1.1-12.zip
```

This will create a file structure underneath the folder ./r_libs/bit

Now here is my question: How can I install only the essential library files that R needs to import? I believe this is the ./r_libs/bit/libs/ folder (I might be wrong). Currently there is plenty of additional folders installed, such as html, help, Meta, and more.

I have tried several options that R CMD INSTALL --help gives me. The description in https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/INSTALL.html tells me to install just the compiled code for another sub-architecture, use --libs-only. However,

```
R CMD INSTALL --libs-only --library=./r_libs ./external/bit_1.1-12.zip
```

gives me an error message that there is no ./r_libs/bit/lib directory. The options --no-html, --no-help seem to not do anything.

I am working on a Windows 7 machine using R add-on package installer 3.0.2.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know you only need the `bit.so` library (that's the only thing the `libs` dir)? Is it for some other package/code you're using? The binary R packages are (generally) the minimum necessary components to effectively use the package on your system.

Comment: I have all packages and dependencies I need in a folder. So I install the whole batch into my r_libs folder. If using R CMD INSTALL creates only the necessary components, then what are the options --no-html, --no-help, --libs-only for?

Comment: You're trying to use options that are for building source packages. I think the true, minimalist install would be `R CMD install  --no-data --no-help --no-demo --no-exec --library=./r_libs ./external/bit_1.1-12.tar.gz` but you get _nothing_ with it but the ability to use pkg functions. Are you that short on disk space?